# How to connect Apache Superset Excel Power Query for data retrieval

Tags: powerquery, apache-superset

I am trying to pull data into **Excel Power Query** through **Apache Superset**.

Right now I have to:

- run SQL queries
- save the data to `.csv` files
- manually import these files into Excel

I'm looking for some alternative (i.e. smarter) way to automate this process of extracting data from Superset into Excel through something like [**Power Query connectors**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/about-power-query-in-excel-7104fbee-9e62-4cb9-a02e-5bfb1a6c536a).

Answer (score 1):

Apache Superset doesn't store any data, it sends SQL queries to source databases.  It would be more efficient for you to query the source database(s) directly.

If for some reason you must go through Superset, you could look into making API calls to fetch a chart's data, as [discussed here on Github](https://github.com/apache/superset/discussions/21757).